# PHP OPcode caching not enabled

Tags: installation

I'm trying to install Drupal 8.0.0-rc4 using Xammp and when I get into the requirements review I get this warning in the list that says:

> PHP OPcode caching can improve your site's performance considerably. It is highly recommended to have OPcache installed on your server.

It has a link for something to download but I'm not sure what to do once I get there. Can someone please help me out? I'm using PHP 5.6.14.

If I move on anyway and try to view my Drupal site I get this:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Questions about how to install a PHP extension are off-topic here, since Drupal doesn't change how you install a PHP extension.